# double clicking inside onCellSelect in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to trigger a function when I double click with it on the specific column. Is it possible to implement with that scenario? I used this code but nothing happens.

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({

...

onCellSelect : function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
        $('#tblPdcNtcShipmentConfirmationCabinetDetails').dblclick(function() {
            if(cellname == "SafetyMargin"){
                showSafetyStockInfo(event,$('#tblPdcNtcShipmentConfirmationCabinetDetails').jqGrid('getRowData',$('#tblPdcNtcShipmentConfirmationCabinetDetails').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow')));
            }
        });
    }

...

});
```

Comment: Have you checked the error console of Firefox, Chrome or Safari? An error message will maybe printed.

Comment: nope. there is no error when i run with it in chrome console.

Comment: Can you add some more code? So we can follow your current situation.

Comment: if you know jquery grid then you know the property behind with it.